# CSS3 Flexbox Layout Module - Align inline-level element when it is a flex item

Tags: css, flexbox

Given that I have got this HTML code:

```
<div>
    <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

div h2 {
    font-size: 1.2307em;
    text-align: center;
}

div p {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0.7692em 0;
}
```

How can I style the anchor so that it is horizontally centred?

Comment: I guess `div { text-align: center; } p { text-align: left; }` would do it.

Comment: @thirtydot, your guess was [spot on](http://jsfiddle.net/E47hE/), please post it as an answer.

Comment: @EliranM.: I'm not so sure it was. I don't think any browser actually supports plain `display: flex` as is in your demo; a vendor prefix of some sort is required.

Comment: @thirtydot, I am aware of your solution but I'm looking for something that implements the flex alignment concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `align-self: center` on the `<a>` (with browser-specific versions of the property too, of course). Inline elements do indeed become flex items, so no need for a block-level wrapper around `<a>`.

That being said, if you're going to be using flexbox, you'll quickly discover that it often requires extra wrapping divs, so you may as well get used to that now. As long as you don't go crazy with them, this isn't a bad thing. The HTML5 spec even talks about how using divs for presentational purposes is appropriate. So don't feel too guilty about it when you just gotta add one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the time I wrote the question align-self wasn't covering the inline-level elements but the spec has changed since and now it is covering them. Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/tRQA1u

Answer (score 0):

one way is this:

1. make your anchor a block element (display:block)
2. give it a width (ie. 80px) and margin auto
3. and finaly give it a width to the container (ie. 100%)

here is the css

```
     div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 1em;
        border: 1px solid #DDD;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width:100%;
    }

    div h2 {
        font-size: 1.2307em;
        text-align: center;
    }

    div p {
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0.7692em 0;
    }

    div a{
        width:80px;
        margin:auto;
        display: block;
    }
```

and the html

```
     <div>
         <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
         <a href="#">Read more</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you improve your solution without using a fixed width?

Comment: Sure! in my code remove all the widths and add "text-align: center" to the anchor (the <a> tag).

the key here is to make the anchor a block element (display:block)

Comment: Thanks but that will turn the whole line a click-able area which is not what I am looking for. I was hoping to see a solution that is implemented by using the flex layout module.

Answer (score 0):

Having an anchor floating like that outside of a paragraph is not good markup. You should put a second paragraph tag around the anchor, and then center that paragraph.

You can also just use this CSS on your code as you have it now:

```
a {
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Do you think every inline-level element should be wrapped with a block-level element like p?

Comment: Yes, I think this is a good guideline. It will help your layout have solid structure and help your design principles as you're working out what goes where, and takes up what sort of space.

Comment: I like using just enough mark-up necessary to define the content semantically and style it. Introducing purely layout related tags can easily lead you to divitis. Also if you are working on a modular HTML code where it is presented differently then the layout tags become redundant. So for example if I needed to display an anchor on the right hand side I would float it to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the "align-self" flex property helps to align an element in cross-axis. But it can only be applied to flex items and inline-level elements like <a>, <span>, etc. are not regarded as flex items. So the only solution that I can think of is wrapping it with a block-level element like <div> or <p> and using "text-align" property.

```
<div><a href="#">Read more</a></div>

div a { text-align: center; }
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#align-self